# How to hide/show thymeleaf fields based on controller condition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC application with thymeleaf.

Depending on a condition tested in the controller method I want to show or hide an html element from the view (input, span, div, button...).

How to do that? For instance, in asp.net you can do myButton.Visible = false (or true) if you want or don't want to display it.

Anything like that available in thymeleaf with spring? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it by passing the attribute via
[`org.springframework.ui.Model`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html) and use Thymeleaf's [`th:if` attribute](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation)

Demo:

```java
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MealController {

    @GetMapping("/order")
    public String getCondition(@RequestParam(required = false) String myMeal, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("meal", myMeal);
        return "meal/meal-site";
    }
}
```

resources/templates/meal-site.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hot Dog?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:if="'hotdog' == ${meal}">A hotdog! </div>
    <div th:if="'hotdog' != ${meal}">Not a hotdog </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly. Works with a ModelAndView as well. Thank you. Answer accepted.

Comment: What if you have a dropdown control that sets "meal" and you want the respective div to show up. Is the template reactive, or do you have to bring JavaScript into it?